# recover default behavior of arrow keys rather than having them produce ABCD, when I map <esc>

Tags: key-bindings, escape

My question is related to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/849693/moving-cursor-with-the-arrow-keys-in-vim-normal-mode-inserts-abcd-charactershttps://askubuntu.com/questions/849693/moving-cursor-with-the-arrow-keys-in-vim-normal-mode-inserts-abcd-characters) which for some reason was closed. Here's my `.vimrc` file

```
set cpoptions=BceFs$    ":compatibility flags with /usr/ucb/vi
set hlsearch
hi Search ctermfg=white  ctermbg=black cterm=NONE
hi IncSearch ctermfg=Black  ctermbg=lightyellow cterm=bold,underline,reverse
nnoremap <esc> :noh<return><esc>
```

When I search, for a pattern it is highlighted; when I hit `esc`, the highlighting is removed, however the arrow keys insert `ABCD`.

When I remove the line `nnoremap <esc> :noh<return><esc>`, I recover the default behavior of the arrow keys, but I lose the desired property of the `esc` key.

Could somebody please explain how I can maintain the property that I want from the `esc` key while preserving the default behavior of the arrow keys?

Some posts suggest that adding the line `set nocompatible`
to my `.vimrc` file will fix the problem, but in my configuration, it doesn't.    Still others suggest `set term=cons25`, which doesn't work for me either.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: In insert mode, or in the terminal, press Ctrl-V and then one of the arrow keys. What do you get?

Comment: do not remap esc key, or at least wait until VimEnter has fired.

Comment: @muru   Ctrl V followed by up arrow returns ^[[A,   other arrows return similarly,

Comment: @Christian_Brabandt,   I don't know what you mean "wait until VimEnter has fired, could you explain please?    If I had to choose one, I'd choose the remap the `esc` key rather than have the arrow keys work, but I imagine somehow it's possible to have both.   If the `esc` is the problem could you suggest another key remapping that I could use instead?   I tried replacing `esc` with `del` but it didn't work

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Creating the mapping later on won't fix this particular issue, unfortunately.

Comment: @LeoSimon You can read about how to delay the `<esc>` mapping [on this related question](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2614/why-does-this-esc-normal-mode-mapping-affect-startup). It won't help this issue, though.

Comment: @Rich not from my experience. It usually only confuses Vim when it starts up because of the several requests it sends to the terminal. But once started up, it usually works just fine (see also the answer to the question you linked above)

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I wrote the question to which you refer, and I implemented a slightly variation of your answer to fix it, as detailed in my own answer to that question. However it doesn't fix this issue. (I'm certain of this, because I've tested it). If you have an alternative implementation that does fix this issue, I'd definitely like to use it, though, so let me know!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure of the solution (or if there is one) but I can explain roughly what's causing the problem to occur.

When you press an arrow key on your keyboard, what your terminal actually passes to Vim is a ANSI escape code, which is, literally, an `<Esc>` character followed by a sequence of other characters. The sequences for the arrow keys are:

- <kbd>up</kbd>: <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>[</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>
- <kbd>down</kbd>: <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>[</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>
- <kbd>right</kbd>: <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>[</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>
- <kbd>left</kbd>: <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>[</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>

You can test this out by typing the sequences quickly and watching the cursor move around (without your mapping in place).

But because of your mapping, the <kbd>Esc</kbd> at the beginning of the escape sequence is transformed into something else, and the escape sequence is broken.

I'm not 100% sure precisely how this results in Vim entering insert mode and then inserting the final character of the escape sequence as text, but, unfortunately, this is the result. (You end up in insert mode via the `o` in `:noh`, but I'm not sure what happens to the rest of the sequence/mapping. hopefully someone else can explain in detail.)

FWIW: This problem does not occur in GUI Vim: it's specifically a terminal issue.

Comment: Thanks for this, @rich.    As I mentioned to Christian, could I maybe use a different key to accomplish what `esc` accomplished in the above?    Eg., I never use the `calc` or `Delete` or `PrntScr`  keys on my keypad during `vi` sessions, but don't know how to access them in `vi`

Comment: @LeoSimon You sure could. I don't think you can (easily) use any of the keys you suggested, but there are some good suggestions in the other question I linked to. Otherwise, see `:help map-which-keys`.

Comment: I looked at the other link but decided that the easiest approach was your last one.    Accordingly, I choose F2, which doesn't do anything else in my setup, and replaced the offensive line with `nnoremap <F2> :noh<return><F2>`, i.e., simply replaced `esc` with `F2`.    But unfortunately, it didn't work.     I'm flying blind here:   was the syntax special for `esc`.    Thanks very much for your help!   Leo