# Why does the cursor end up on the wrong line when <Esc><Esc> is mapped to something?

Tags: key-bindings, command-line, cursor, mouse

In `vim --clean`, I insert these lines:

```
One
Two
Three
Four
Five
Six
```

Then I do:

```
:set mouse=a
:nnoremap <Esc><Esc> <Nop>
```

(From my observations, the mapping could be to anything. `:nnoremap <Esc><Esc> :echom "Hello"<CR>` would work just as well for this demonstration).

1. I position the cursor on the first column of the first line.
2. Then, I input (but not <kbd>Enter</kbd>) something in the command line area (e.g. `:blabla`).
3. At this point, I press <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>, and I use my mouse to click on `Six` (the last line in the buffer).

Surprise: the cursor is positioned on the third line (`Three`)! What could be the reason for such a strange behavior?

Even more intriguing, doing `:nnoremap ; :` and repeating the steps above does not move the cursor at all! Instead, something like `:2;6M` would be displayed in the echo area. It seems that the format of the echoed message is: colon, followed by the column number of the mouse click, semicolon, followed by the line number of the mouse click, then an uppercase letter M.

Comment: Can't find any good sources but tired of repeating myself on this, so here's one that's related. Escape should not be remapped, short-answer. https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/11144/10604

Comment: You are defining a normal mode mapping. Your first `<ESC>` is issued in command mode and interpreted as normal. Your second `<ESC>` can be the start of your mapping. Depending on your terminal mouse clicks might be (I don't know for sure) represented as a character sequence starting with `ESC`. In that case the leading `ESC` would trigger your mapping and the remainder of that sequence would be interpreted as normal mode commands.

Comment: @Zoe, @D.BenKnoble The OP isn't mapping a single `ESC`, they're mapping _two_ presses of `ESC`, which shouldn't conflict with terminal escape sequences. I think [Jürgen Krämer has got this one right](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/30812/343).

Answer (score 1):

You are defining a normal mode mapping. Your first <kbd>ESC</kbd> is issued in command mode and thus interpreted as always---it stops command mode. Your second <kbd>ESC</kbd> can be interpreted as the start of your mapping. Depending on your terminal mouse clicks might be (I don't know for sure) represented as a character sequence starting with `ESC`. In that case the second <kbd>ESC</kbd> on the command line in combination with the leading `ESC` of that sequence would trigger your mapping and the remainder of that sequence would be interpreted as normal mode commands.