# How to set up an execute-once mapping

Tags: key-bindings

Autocommands support the `++once` modifier.  I am trying to achieve the same effect for a map.

Instead of coming up with a general solution I have been trying to solve my particular case via a side-effect – I thought it would be easier...

In this case it's a buffer-local map.  The map, in window A, closes window B.  To remove the map once it has executed, I have a `BufLeave` autocmd in window B to remove the map from window A.  However I cannot get the autocmd to find the map.

Here's how I set things up in window A:

```
nnoremap <buffer> <Esc> :<C-U>close_other_window()<CR>
let bufnr = bufnr()
execute "autocmd BufLeave <buffer=".bufnr_of_other_window."> nunmap <buffer=".bufnr."> <Esc>"
```

The problem is the `nunmap` cannot find the map.  There's no error but the map remains in place.  If I use the following instead, it still cannot find the map (perhaps because `<buffer>` is window B's buffer when the autocmd executes):

```
execute "autocmd BufLeave <buffer=".bufnr_of_other_window."> nunmap <buffer> <Esc>"
```

Any tips for this situation or the general case would be appeciated!

Comment: That kind of sound like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) no? What are you trying to do which requires you to delete some mappings like this? Anyway what about getting rid of the autocmd and letting the mapping delete itself? Maybe you could update `close_other_window()` so that it closes the window _and_ delete the mapping: This way you wouldn't have to worry if the mapping is local to another buffer since you will run the command from the same buffer the mapping is defined for.

Comment: I agree with everything statox says. If you still decide you want to use something like your current approach, though, please include `close_other_window()` as it may have relevance.

Comment: Re xy: I addressed that in my second paragraph.  I'm now trying the general solution: `nnoremap <buffer> <Esc> :blah<Bar>nunmap <buffer> <Esc><CR>` but without success.

Comment: I still think it would be worth it to explain why you want to delete a mapping this way that's what I meant when I talked about the xy problem. Now for the command you gave in you last comment: I believe that if your replace `<Esc>` with e.g. `a` the mapping would work. The issue is that your string `<Esc>` is probably interpreted as an escape character and not the literal string `<Esc>` (check the output of  `:map <esc>` to be sure). To fix that you'll probably have to mess with escaping, maybe using `execute` with simple quotes to run the `nnoremap` command would help but I'm not sure.

Comment: You probably really don't want to map escape. For example, https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/11144/10604, and its linked/related questions on the right sidebar.

Comment: @statox I think you are right.  I have tried all sorts of escaping, e.g. `\ltEsc>` etc, but hadn't thought of using `execute` – which approach quickly led me to the answer.

Comment: I agree with everyone about it being better not to map `<Esc>`.  It's not something I would do myself, and it's also why I want the map to remove itself.

Answer (score 1):

Following @statox's [comment](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/31457/how-to-set-up-an-execute-once-mapping#comment57606_31457) I found this solution:

```
nnoremap <buffer> <Esc> :blah<Bar>execute "nunmap <buffer> \e"<CR>
```

(The `\e` for `<Esc>` is in the docs for `expr-string`.)

Comment: You shouldn't need `:execute` for the second part. Simply `...<Bar>nunmap <buffer> <Esc>` should do. Or does it not work, for some reason? Ah, I think you might need an extra escape here, so `...<Bar>nunmap <lt>buffer> <lt>Esc>`... Yeah, looks ugly. Better yet would be to put both the `:blah` and the `:nunmap` in a function, then you don't need to deal with escaping.

Comment: I already tried all that before posting the question.  Did you?  I agree about using a function; I'm curious to get it working inline.